# Most efficient way to tail a rolling log file in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, logging

What is the most efficient way to tail log files that are rolled over when they get to a certain size. Some app log files can get quite large, 100+ MB.

For example:
Tailing "file.log".

After it gets to 25MB, that file is renamed ("file.log.1"). A new blank fresh "file.log" is created to replace it.

One option I found is: PowerShell cmdlet Get-Content

```
gc file.log -wait -tail 1
```

Anyone know if it is *smart enough* to know that a file has rolled over (re-named, re-created) as such no line is missed during the roll over?

Or if some checks are needed. If so can I get some ideas please.

Any better options for Windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use below Powershell command:

```
get-content {file_name} -tail 10 -wait
```

Comment: How does this allow the command to handle the file being rolled over? What does adding the braces do? I can't find documentation of this.

Answer (score 2):

I would do that in a loop.

```
while($true) { if( Test-Path .\file.log ) { Get-Content .\file.log -Wait -Tail 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue} }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the number of lines you have to validate then you could use something like below ("-" indicates you are reading from line 1 bottom up)

(Get-Content $TargetFileLocation)[-1..-5] | Select-String -Pattern "TEXT YOU LOOK FOR"

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is confirmation that gc can tail a log file uninterrupted when the file is rolled over. Has anyone done testing on this, for the part I did it seems to be but I am not sure if the file gets big.